# Option page not updating multiple records in settings api

Tags: plugins, options, settings-api

Hi i am new to wordpress plugin development. i have issues with settings api. please help if you can.

Below is my problem.

```
  function load_plugin() {

    add_settings_section('plugin_main', '<h1>Ticker Settings</h1>', 'plugin_section_text', 'plugin');
    add_settings_field('plugin_text_string', 'Title text', 'plugin_setting_string', 'plugin', 'plugin_main');
    add_settings_field('post_title_link', 'Link', 'plugin_link_setting', 'plugin', 'plugin_main');

    register_setting('plugin_options', 'plugin_options');
    register_setting('post_title_link', 'post_title_link');
}

function plugin_section_text() {
    echo '<p>Change your post ticker title and give link to.</p>';
}

function plugin_setting_string() {
    echo "<input id='plugin_text_string' name='plugin_options' size='40' type='text' value='" . get_option('plugin_options') . "' />";
}

function plugin_link_setting() {
    echo "<input id='post_title_link' name='post_title_link' size='40' type='text' value='" . get_option('post_title_link') . "' />";
}

add_action('admin_init', 'load_plugin');

function post_ticker_setting() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php
            settings_fields('plugin_options');
            settings_fields('post_title_link');
            do_settings_sections('plugin');
            ?>
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

This is the code. the problem i am facing is the last record which is link it is updating in database but the title text is not updating in database.

So please help me find solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `id` from `plugin_text_string` to `plugin_options`.

Comment: thanks for replay first. i have changed `id` but still not working.

Comment: most of the time where ID are use there is a change of 
Conflict so i would suggest you to add a Prefix to you IDs like `myIne_plugin_options` Note: myIne is a Prefix goes in front of every ID you use, please try this, it might solve your issue.

Comment: No it's not working still by changing `ID`, but if i am commenting the link code then it's working with the same code. Both combined not working.